# Local SQL Server won't work: "No process is on the other end of the pipe."

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm just starting out learning Entity Framework Core. I'm trying to use a local database in a sample project, however, when I call `DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer` in my code:

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) 
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = KindleDictionaryApp");
}
```

I get the following exception:

> SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.
> (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

I just installed the [Data storage and processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver16) workload in VS2022. As far as I understand, this should work out of the box. I tried rebooting after adding the workload.

My understanding is that with EF Core, if the database name specified for `Initial Catalog` does not exist, it should be automatically created. My connection string in `UseSqlServer` looks identical (outside of the database name) to the one in [Julie Lerman's EF Core 6 Pluralsight course sample project](https://github.com/julielerman/PluralsightEFCore6Fundamentals/blob/EFCore6/M02%20Building%20Your%20FIrst%20App/After/PublisherData/PubContext.cs).

I am able to connect to the local SQL Server using SSMS.

**Update:** If I add `Integrated Security=SSPI` to the connection string, the exception changes:

> SqlException: Cannot open database "KindleDictionaryApp" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'STEAMBOX\mikeb'.

`STEAMBOX\mikeb` is my Windows account. I log in locally with a Windows Hello PIN, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: [From EF Core 7, it encrypt by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#encrypt-defaults-to-true-for-sql-server-connections). Try to add in your connection string 'Encrypt=false' or `TrustServerCertificate=true`.

Comment: @vernou - Thanks, but neither of those properties worked for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the database did not exist because I missed the important step of running the `Update-Database` cmdlet in the Package Manager console. This cmdlet applies the schema that was defined in an [EF Core migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).